# Annotating the rightmost upper corner of a cell of a ROTATED table with a small letter/symbol

Tags: tables, rotating, annotations

(second post) The previous answer works fine for the tables I have, except for big tables that I need to rotate has shown in the next code. I played with the first two parameters of the solution proposed (the '2' of 'wide-2' and the '.3' of '\hspace{.3\tabcolsep)', but did not manage to find the proper setting of these parameters. The code with a rotated matrix is given below.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\PTSConstraint}[1]{\constraint{$g$\_$f$\_{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Pre}[1]{\ensuremath\overrightarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\Suf}[1]{\ensuremath\overleftarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\Neither}{\AGG{\Pre{C},\Suf{C}}}
\newcommand{\Creates}{\Fea(\Pre{D},\Suf{D},\Con)}
\newcommand{\ExtendLeft}{\Fea(\Pre{C},\Pre{D},\Suf{D},\Con)}
\newcommand{\ExtendRight}{\Fea(\Suf{C},\Pre{D},\Suf{D},\Con)}
\newcommand{\Extendboth}{\Fea(\Pre{C},\Suf{C},\Pre{D},\Suf{D},\Con)}
\newcommand{\ExtendbothHat}{\Fea(\Pre{C},\Suf{C},\Pre{D},\Suf{D},\ConHat)}
\newcommand{\Agg}{g}
\newcommand{\AGG}[1]{\phi_\Agg(#1)}
\newcommand{\Fea}{\ensuremath{\phi_f}} 
\newcommand{\Con}{\delta_f^{i+1}}
\newcommand{\ConHat}{\hat{\delta}_f^{i+1}}

\newcommand{\AnnotatedCreatesChar}{$\diamond$}
\newcommand{\AnnotatedExtendLeftChar}{$\blacktriangleright$}
\newcommand{\AnnotatedExtendRightChar}{$\blacktriangleleft$}
\newcommand{\AnnotatedExtendbothChar}{$\square$}
\newcommand{\AnnotatedExtendbothHatChar}{$\blacksquare$}

\newcommand{\AnnotatedCreates}{\eqmakebox[wide-2]{$\Creates$}\rlap{\hspace{.3\tabcolsep}\raisebox{.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\scriptsize \AnnotatedCreatesChar}}}
\newcommand{\AnnotatedExtendLeft}{\eqmakebox[wide-2]{$\ExtendLeft$}\rlap{\hspace{.3\tabcolsep}\raisebox{.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\scriptsize \AnnotatedExtendLeftChar}}}
\newcommand{\AnnotatedExtendRight}{\eqmakebox[wide-2]{$\ExtendRight$}\rlap{\hspace{.3\tabcolsep}\raisebox{.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\scriptsize \AnnotatedExtendRightChar}}}
\newcommand{\AnnotatedExtendboth}{\eqmakebox[wide-2]{$\Extendboth$}\rlap{\hspace{.3\tabcolsep}\raisebox{.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\scriptsize \AnnotatedExtendbothChar}}}
\newcommand{\AnnotatedExtendbothHat}{\eqmakebox[wide-2]{$\ExtendbothHat$}\rlap{\hspace{.3\tabcolsep}\raisebox{.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\scriptsize \AnnotatedExtendbothHatChar}}}

\begin{table}[h]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\scalebox{0.85}{\rotatebox{90}{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$s$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$b$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$c$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$d$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$e$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$f$} \\
 \cline{2-8}
{$s$} & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ \\
 \cline{2-8}
{$a$} & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedExtendRight & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedCreates & $\Neither$ \\
\cline{2-8}
{$b$} & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedCreates & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedCreates & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedExtendRight \\
\cline{2-8}
{$c$} & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedExtendLeft & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedExtendboth & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedExtendLeft & $\Neither$ \\
\cline{2-8}
{$d$} & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedCreates & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedExtendRight \\
\cline{2-8}
{$e$} & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedCreates & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedExtendRight & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedCreates & $\Neither$ \\
\cline{2-8}
{$f$} & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedExtendLeft & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedExtendLeft & $\Neither$ & \AnnotatedExtendboth \\
\cline{2-8}
\end{tabular}
}}
\caption{Parametrised glue matrix for any zigzag constraint}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

(initial post) Given the following table, I would like to annotate some cells without changing the cell size; the annotation should be in the upper rightmost corner of some cell and shoud consist of one single tiny uppercase letter (or one tiny symbol).

If I start writing the symbol in a standard way, I will get two problems:
(1) the cell size changes,
(2) the symbol is not in the upper righmost corner.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\Pre}[1]{\ensuremath\overrightarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\Suf}[1]{\ensuremath\overleftarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\Neither}{\AGG{\Pre{C},\Suf{C}}}
\newcommand{\Creates}{\Fea(\Pre{D},\Suf{D},\Con)}
\newcommand{\Agg}{g}
\newcommand{\AGG}[1]{\phi_\Agg(#1)}
\newcommand{\Fea}{\ensuremath{\phi_f}} 
\newcommand{\Con}{\delta_f^{i+1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$s$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$t$} \\
\cline{2-4}
{$s$} & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ \\
\cline{2-4}
{$r$} & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ &  $\Creates$ \\
\cline{2-4}
{$t$} & $\Neither$ & $\Creates$ & $\Creates$ \\
\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Parametrised glue matrix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you do the table in Ti*k*Z, this is easy, but maybe that's overkill?

Comment: Why do you use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` when the cells are already `c` specified?

Comment: I did not want to use TikZ if possible, because TikZ is a bottleneck when compiling a file containing a lot of figures (even if one uses the externalized option in a way that takes advantage of all the cores of your machine).

Comment: As I say, it is overkill here. Werner's solution should avoid that. Externalisation doesn't use multiple cores. What it does is avoids recompiling pictures which haven't changed. So it should only be a bottleneck when you've changed the code of a picture - and it should only affect that picture. However, if you add or remove pictures, you get additional runs unless you've named your pictures. This is a significant issue with the library, but is not so difficult to workaround to avoid the defaults.

Comment: I know externalisation avoid recompiling the pictures which haven't changed. But the first compilation that use externalisation of a document containing thousand of Tikz pictures can takes hours (rather than a few minutes) when using one single core. But you can organise your figures in mutiples files and use a makefile to externalise figures in parallel. And many of my pictures are produced by a program, so that I have to rebuild all of them: therefore quite often, externalisation save me time only in the 2nd and 3rd time of a LaTeX compilation.

Comment: Apparently the problem comes from using '\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}' rather than '\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}' (and has nothing to do with rotating the picture). But if I use '10pt' the figure does not fit on one page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an idea: We store the content of the widest element in a box and then store the to-be-superscripted-cell in a box of the same width. This will not affect the table/column width. Then one can place the superscript in a zero-width box and move it into place.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\Pre}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\Suf}[1]{\overleftarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\Neither}{\AGG{\Pre{C}, \Suf{C}}}
\newcommand{\Creates}{\Fea(\Pre{D}, \Suf{D}, \Con)}
\newcommand{\Agg}{g}
\newcommand{\AGG}[1]{\phi_\Agg(#1)}
\newcommand{\Fea}{\phi_f}
\newcommand{\Con}{\delta_f^{i + 1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
  \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c | c | }
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$s$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$t$} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    $s$ & $\Neither$ & \eqmakebox[wide-2]{$\Neither$}\rlap{\textsuperscript{2}} & $\Neither$ \\
    \cline{2-4}
    $r$ & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$ & $\Creates$ \\
    \cline{2-4}
    $t$ & $\Neither$ & \eqmakebox[wide-2]{$\Creates$} & $\Creates$ \\
    \cline{2-4}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Parametrised glue matrix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Of course, more movement of the `\textsuperscript{2}` is possible to perfectly position it, like

[image]

```
% ...
\eqmakebox[wide-2]{$\Neither$}%
  \rlap{\hspace{.5\tabcolsep}\raisebox{.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\scriptsize 2}}
% ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that satisfies the requirement that the cell size is unchanged. However, you may need to adjust the distances `yshift` and `right of` by hand.

**EDIT**: If you don't want to use Ti*k*Z and/or do not like to adjust things by hand, you may use `\newcommand{\MarkCell}[2]{\hfill#1\hspace*{3pt}\makebox[-3pt][l]{${}^{#2}$}}`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\Pre}[1]{\ensuremath\overrightarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\Suf}[1]{\ensuremath\overleftarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\Neither}{\AGG{\Pre{C},\Suf{C}}}
\newcommand{\Creates}{\Fea(\Pre{D},\Suf{D},\Con)}
\newcommand{\Agg}{g}
\newcommand{\AGG}[1]{\phi_\Agg(#1)}
\newcommand{\Fea}{\ensuremath{\phi_f}} 
\newcommand{\Con}{\delta_f^{i+1}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339526/confusion-over-use-of-tikzmark
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\MarkCell}[2]{\hfill#1\hspace*{3pt}\makebox[-3pt][l]{${}^{#2}$}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$s$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$r$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$t$} \\
\cline{2-4}
{$s$} & $\Neither$ & $\Neither$\tikzmark{pfft} & $\Neither$ \\
\cline{2-4}
{$r$} & $\Neither$ & \hfill$\Neither$\hfill \hspace*{3pt}\makebox[-3pt][l]{${}^3$} &  $\Creates$ \\
\cline{2-4}
{$t$} & \MarkCell{$\Neither$}{4} & $\Creates$ & \MarkCell{$\Creates$}{5} \\
\cline{2-4}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Parametrised glue matrix}
\end{table}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\node[anchor=south,right=3mm of pfft,yshift=3mm]{${\scriptstyle 2}$};} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure the example will typeset that table. Wrong copy-paste?

Comment: @egreg It does, but you're right: there was some unnecessary stuff after `\end{document}`. Grazie!